# custom iterator which can traverse iterator

Tags: java, iterator

how to custom an iterator can traverse list which element is also a list, for example {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, this custom iterator can output {1,2,3,4,5,6}

```
class CustomIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{

public CustomIterator(Iterator<Iterator<E>> root){
    //add implement code...
}

//add implement code...

}
```

Comment: This sounds like an assignment. What have you already tried?

Comment: I try to implement it yesterday, I have no idea about it. I don't understand the constructor has a parameter Iterator, I look the ArrayList source code, I think at least need a Collection class out side, and this iterator should be inner class at this Collection

Comment: Firstly the `Iterator` interface is well known and easy to look up, there is no need to paste it here. Secondly this is not a place to give people assignments and have them do it for you. You have to try your best and then tell us where and why you are stuck. Saying things like "you need to fill into this class", "you can add any code, but make sure", and "BTW, don't forgot" is sure to appear disrespectful.

Comment: "I don't understand the constructor has a parameter Iterator" - do you not understand why there is a parameter `Iterator<Iterator<E>> root`? It's simply the input to the assignment. No, you do not need any collections (hence using O(1) memory), including ArrayList. This assignment can be done using only iterators. What is essential is that you understand how iterators work, particularly what they are meant to do.

Comment: yes, I know iterator use cursor point the current element, for example: ArrayList, it must be use get method of list to retrieve data, but there is have a Collection, like the source code:Object[] elementData =     ArrayList.this.elementData;
            if (i >= elementData.length)
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            cursor = i + 1;
            return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];

Comment: if I have not a Collection, how do I implement next method?

Comment: actually, I am not very clear about this question

Comment: @AlexHall I have some reservations w.r.t. to the constructor parameter. Given that the ultimate purpose of the exercise is to permit "flat" iteration over a `List<List<Integer>> listOfList`: how would you call this constructor?

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for my words, my english is not good, I have modified the words which you say

Comment: @Tony Is this the verbatim (!) text of the assignment, in full?

Comment: @laune I do not think that this is strictly for flattening lists. In theory you could get an iterator of iterators from many sources. When the question shows "{{1},{2,3},{4,5,6}} -> {1,2,3,4,5,6}" I think it is just a visual representation of a test case in the assignment, i.e. `root.next().next() == 1; root.next().next() == 2;` etc.

Comment: yes, yesterday, I try to pass List<List<Integer>> to the constructor, but failed, because it need Iterator type parameter, List<List<Integer>> is not a Iterator type, so I pass List.iterator to the constructor, and the generic is not permitted

Comment: @AlexHall Quite - so how do you propose to get this root from some data structure?

Comment: no, root.next().next() == 1 maybe right, in this if you continue call root.next().next() it maybe 2, then continue call root.next().next(), it will 4, 3 will miss by you second call root.next

Comment: for example: first call root.next(), got {1}, so {1}.next() is 1, right. second root.next() got {2,3}, {2,3}.next() is 2, third root.next() got {4,5,6}, {4,5,6}.next() is 4, 3 miss

Comment: @Tony make sure you understand what iterators are meant to do, why we have them, etc. Right now you do not. Iterators do not need to be tied to a collection. They can represent lines from a file, results from a database, characters from a TCP socket, mathematical sequences, anything. Once you really understand what `next()` and `hasNext()` are for you should understand that you can implement them using only `next()` and `hasNext()` on the given input iterators. There is no need to import anything other than Iterator to solve this assignment.

Comment: maybe I can add cursor to track if every sub list is empty, and if empty, I do cursor++, if not, the cursor still point the current not empty sub list, but I have not a Collection

Comment: @laune I was not trying to suggest that calling `root.next().next()` a third time would give 3. I was just saying here is some of what we can expect from this sample in terms of the vocabulary of iterators only.

Comment: @Tony stop thinking in terms of lists, sublists, and collections. I promise you do not need them. What you need is a field to keep track of which *subIterator* you are on.

Comment: Alex, thank you, could you provide some more detail about iterator, I want to study it

Comment: @laune I could definitely write a class implementing `Iterator<Iterator<E>>` which took a `List<List<E>>` as a constructor parameter but I have no reason to make that effort.

Comment: @Tony if I give you the iterator `root` which is visually represented by `{{1},{2,3},{4,5,6}}`, what does calling `root.hasNext()` give?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basically "give me the code" without showing any effort by the OP.

Comment: @Alex, I think we can define instance filed root and use this.root = root in constructor

Comment: I'm willing to push him to figure it out himself. I think it's likely that iterators as an abstract concept really are too mystical at the moment.

Comment: @Tony I don't understand what you mean "we can define instance filed root"

Comment: @laune, this is full, we can add any code in implement class

Comment: let me change the question description

Comment: @Henry, i tried yesterday, but have no idea, i just not put my code which is not working here, not you said without any effort

Comment: @Alex, I don't understand your words about@Tony if I give you the iterator root which is visually represented by {{1},{2,3},{4,5,6}}, what does calling root.hasNext() give? sorry for my bad english, could your explain more

Comment: @AlexHall Ah, that's just what I wanted to hear: that you have to implement (!) `Iterator<Iterator<E>>` based on some nested `Iterable<Iterable<E>>` so that you call that constructor. At the moment, I don't see the benefit of this two-tiered approach.

Comment: @laune it's an assignment meant to test understanding of iterators, and I think it's doing exactly that extremely well.

Comment: @Tony [here](http://goo.gl/F6qts8) is a project containing some iterators (including a nested one) that do not use any collections. Play around with it. Make sure you fully understand what it does and how the code works, particularly the implementations of `next()` and `hasNext()`. When you are stuck, ask questions about it. When you understand it, we will use it to think about solving your assignment.

Comment: @Alex, thanks, I will do it

Comment: Let's continue the discussion in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90676/discussion-about-custom-iterator-which-can-traverse-iterator

Comment: @AlexHall, i have not enough reputation to chat, could you heve time? we can talk about this question more detail, I can show you my code

Comment: @Tony let's talk here: https://tlk.io/javaiterators

Comment: @AlexHall, i can't send message in codebunk

Comment: @AlexHall, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a lot of time on this question, finally i figure out it, below is the full implementation and test code, thank @AlexHall's great help.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class IteratorFlattener<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private Iterator<Iterator<E>> root;
    private Iterator<E> sub;
    public IteratorFlattener(Iterator<Iterator<E>> root) {
        this.root = root;
        if(root.hasNext()){
            this.sub = root.next();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        if(sub != null){
            if(sub.hasNext()){
                return true;
            }
            if(root.hasNext()){
                sub = root.next();
                return sub.hasNext();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public E next(){
        if(sub == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("root iterator was empty");
        }
        return sub.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(){
        if(sub == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("root iterator was empty");
        }
        sub.remove();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("start to test traverse");
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add(1);
        List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        l2.add(2);
        l2.add(3);
        List<Integer> l3 = new ArrayList<>();
        l3.add(4);
        l3.add(5);
        l3.add(6);
        List<Iterator<Integer>> root = new ArrayList<>();
        root.add(l1.iterator());
        root.add(l2.iterator());
        root.add(l3.iterator());
        IteratorFlattener it = new IteratorFlattener<>(root.iterator());
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }

        System.out.println("start to test remove method");
        l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add(1);
        l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        l2.add(2);
        l2.add(3);
        l3 = new ArrayList<>();
        l3.add(4);
        l3.add(5);
        l3.add(6);
        root = new ArrayList<>();
        root.add(l1.iterator());
        root.add(l2.iterator());
        root.add(l3.iterator());
        int i = 0;
        it = new IteratorFlattener<>(root.iterator());
        while(it.hasNext() && i < 3){
            it.next();
            it.remove();
            i++;
        }
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a small problem in your code: it does not work to call `next()` a few times in a row without calls to `hasNext()` in between.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but an extended comment that does not fit in the regrettably limited comment format.

Here is a small program that constructs a `Iterator<Iterator<Integer>>`. You can use this sort of thing to build test cases for your CustomIterator. All that your class is going to get is a testIterator reference, and from that it should be able to iterate over the contents of the original Integer arrays.

(I took the "public" off CustomIterator just so I could put it in one file with my main method. You would not do that.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] main) {
    Iterator<Integer> i1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1}).iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> i2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2,3}).iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> i3 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{4,5,6}).iterator();
    List<Iterator<Integer>> allIterators = new ArrayList<>();
    allIterators.add(i1);
    allIterators.add(i2);
    allIterators.add(i3);

    Iterator<Iterator<Integer>> testIterator = allIterators.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> myIterator = new CustomIterator<>(testIterator);

    while(myIterator.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(myIterator.next());
    }

  }
}

class CustomIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{

public CustomIterator(Iterator<Iterator<E>> root){
    //add implement code...
}

//add implement code...

}
```

Comment: You violated the O(1) constraint with that  `List<Iterator<Integer>>`.

Comment: @laune That constraint applies to the implementation of CustomIterator, which I did not supply. There are no constraints at all on the test code, which is all I wrote.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, thanks for your code, this really helpful for me